# How do I get a batch file execute at a specific time?

Tags: batch-file

I'm trying to create a batch file which starts a program to monitor processes for example at 1 a.m and continues for an hour and then around 2 a.m stops this program and saves the log file to specific location.

START /MAX C:\Procmon.exe

How can I do this?

Answer (score 3):

Will you be running this through windows scheduler, if so you can stop the task running after a period of time, or when you want it to restart it.

Answer (score 0):

If you are lucky enough to not be running on Vista(*) the "AT" command might be of use to you, with this it would be possible to issue the command you describe in your question at 1am.

Then you would schedule a second command using "AT" at 2am to use the "TASKKILL" command to stop the process, if you are happy to have the command terminated with prejudice.

Failing this, write a tiny program which stays resident in memory and executes both the 'start' and 'stop' instructions when it determines it's the correct time to do either.

(*) I've experimented with AT on Vista and it doesn't seem to work for me, your mileage may vary. The task scheduler also seems equally as suspect.

Comment: Remember that on Vista you have to use `schtasks` instead of `at` to get access to the full task scheduler functionality. Or just use the GUI for that. And what do you mean with "The task scheduler also seems equally as suspect"? `at` *is* an interface to the Windows Task Scheduler. And you don't need to create a second task with `taskkill`, you can just set the task to end after a certain time in the Task Scheduler (see Iain's answer).

Comment: Johannes, thanks for the pointer to the schtasks command, I wasn't aware of that.

It's probably not clear from my comment but I've had limited success using the task scheduler, having a nightly process which shuts down a couple of programs running on my development machine if I forget to do so before leaving the office.

The scheduled task to run the batch file works fine for a random amount of time before the task stops working and has to be re-created before it will start working again.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't use a batch file for this. The Windows Task Scheduler is exactly for this kind of task and much more powerful.